# Play mp3 online

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I have a url: `"http://my_server/song.mp3"`

My code:

```
String url_song="http://my_server/song.mp3";
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url_song);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

But it have error (100 0), can not play, i try to download this file and play it in local, it's ok.
So, MediaPlayer have error when play online?

Can someone help me?

Thank all!

Comment: Does the virtual machine throw an exception? Which?

Comment: This is exception:
E/MediaPlayer(20915): error (100, 0)
W/AudioSystem(542): AudioPolicyService server died!
W/System.err(20915): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x64
W/AudioSystem(542): AudioFlinger server died!
W/System.err(20915):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)

Comment: Sang Nguyen, I am having the same problem. Were you able to fix it or find a work around?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Network traffic can never be in the UI thread in Android. Use an `AsyncTask`.

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
    public Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        String url_song="http://my_server/song.mp3";
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url_song);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}.execute();
```

Also, make sure you have the Internet permission in your manifest.

Comment: Thank Mark Buikema, i used AsyncTask, but it show the same error. I sure, i added internet permission

Answer (score 0):

your error log shows IOException so check if the exact file is actually. there also use prepareAsync for network streams as it prepares the stream in the background try this piece of code to. Also implement OnPreparedListener in your class and start the playback in the onPrepared method there.

```
String url_song="http://my_server/song.mp3";
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    try{
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url_song);
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException
                | IllegalStateException | IOException e){
     Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
     }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) { mMediaPlayer.start();}
```

Comment: Thank Eno, I used your code and this is log:
W/AudioSystem(353): AudioPolicyService server died!
W/AudioSystem(27985): AudioFlinger server died!
W/IMediaDeathNotifier(27985): media server died
E/MediaPlayer(27985): error (100, 0)
W/AudioSystem(353): AudioFlinger server died!
E/MediaPlayer(27985): Error (100,0)

Don't have error log:
W/System.err(20915): at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)

Comment: this simply means that your media server has died i.e not available ensure that your media server or host or wherever the file you are trying to play is up and running.

Comment: I play some url else, but don't have the same error, it play ok, just some url error, i don't know anything wrong with them :(

Comment: Check this link to make sure that the mp3 confirms to the android approved media formats  http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: this is my file: http://download1473.mediafire.com/lnab3d2y3nxg/zkx4vfoeqcs3o7y/848.mp3

Answer (score 0):

use the Intent.ACTION_VEW

```
String url_song="http://my_server/song.mp3";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                                                                          
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url_song), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

This would let the user select the third party app they want the remote mp3 to be played on. Similar to when you open up an image and a dialog shows up letting you select what app you want to use to open up the image.

Comment: But i want to play it on my application, i had try play it with default player on android but the same problem, i download this file and play it ok

Comment: could you at least post your code so we can check it out?